# Css Page break causing extra page break after table in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have the following html file...these are the entire contents:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1">
<style type="text/css">
    P.breakhere
    {            
        page-break-after: always;
    }
</style>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            [Contents of page 1]
            <p class="breakhere" style="width: 100%; text-align: right; font-weight: bold;">
                Continued...
            </p>
            [Contents of page 2]
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    [More of page 2]
</body>
</html>
```

This is printing as 3 pages in IE 8 (version: 8.0.7601.17514) installed on Windows 7 Professional SP1

This should only be printing as 2 pages, but an additional pagebreak is inserted after the table element is closed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: do you get the same results printing on Firefox and Chrome?

Comment: No, chrome works perfectly, but firefox doesn't even add the first pagebreak.  But most of our clients are locked down with IE so it has to work with that.

Comment: yea, IE has all sorts of problems with print CSS bugs.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with the page-break-before (or page-break-after) being set on an element inside of a table.

There is no workaround.  It will cause unexpected behavior.  I had to change around the layout of the page to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
page-break-inside:avoid
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebi.asp